# How to remove blue background from app icon? MAUI Hybrid

Tags: blazor-webassembly, maui, hybrid

I use a transparent PNG icon, the application displays correctly in the taskbar, but when I add its shortcut to the desktop, the system adds a blue background. How to fix it?

Correct icon on taskbar:
[image: maui taskbar icon]

Incorrect icon on desktop (shortcut) [image]

Comment: Maybe there is a color set in the project file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#recolor-the-background) ?

Comment: @Poulpynator i didn't set background color 
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" />

Comment: You can try to Right-click on the icon and select Properties, then click the Change icon button. Choose an appropriate icon with transparent icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try set #00 start of the color:

```
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#00FF0000"/>
```

[image]